# Floating point exception debug

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, arm, neon

I am facing a floating point exception problem that I'm not able to explain . 
My asm function exits the loops , restores the arm registers to stack but while returning
to the caller function gives a floating point exception. GDB tells me that a division is the
reason for this , but I don't know where to look for the division as it happens between 
my function returning to the caller function . 
Any leads would be helpful . Thanks a lot .

I've attached a few lines from my gdb.

```
 cmp r1,#0
544     @Loop end
545        bgt .L1
546         vldmia   sp!, {d8-d15}         @ restore VFP/Advanced SIMD
547             ldmfd   sp!,{r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11,r12,lr}
548         .end
(gdb) n
non_trivial_asm () at ../lib/neon_asm/non_trivial_butterfly.asm:547
547             ldmfd   sp!,{r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11,r12,lr}
(gdb) n
__udivsi3 ()
    at /OE/angstrom/build/tmp-angstrom_2008_1/work/i686-armv7a-sdk-angstrom-linux-gn0
810     /OE/angstrom/build/tmp-angstrom_2008_1/work/i686-armv7a-sdk-angstrom-linux-g.
(gdb) n
811     in /OE/angstrom/build/tmp-angstrom_2008_1/work/i686-armv7a-sdk-angstrom-linum
(gdb) 
812     in /OE/angstrom/build/tmp-angstrom_2008_1/work/i686-armv7a-sdk-angstrom-linum
(gdb) 
834     in /OE/angstrom/build/tmp-angstrom_2008_1/work/i686-armv7a-sdk-angstrom-linum
(gdb) 

Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x401665b4 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Can you post your C source code?

Comment: Looks like a divide by zero in `__udivsi3` ?

Comment: Possibly a stack corruption.  What is the code at the caller?  Use `bt`, `up` and `down`.  If the return `lr` is smashed, you may jump to a `__udivsi3()` (or some random code) with bogus arguments.  Please see: [Minimum complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You have given too little information.  It looks like you wrote your own assembler and called from 'C'?  How is it called?

Comment: Either post the related C code or drop the `C` tag.

Comment: @artlessnoise You may have something here . I need to check the lr values at the beginning of the function call and the end . Will see if that is the issue.

Comment: I was not loading the lr register back to pc .
bx lr solved the issue . I feel kind of stupid now. :-|

Comment: This is why you don't program in assembler unless you have to.  Boiler plate prologue/epligue **OR** inline assembler would have avoided your problem.  Don't feel foolish for making a mistake.  Feel foolish if you repeat it.